# ESP 8266 serial error

Tags: esp8266

I am using an ESP8266 [board](http://chrome-extension://klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg/suspended.html#ttl=Amazon.com%3A%20HiLetgo%202pcs%20ESP8266%20NodeMCU%20LUA%20CP2102%20ESP-12E%20Internet%20WiFi%20Development%20Board%20Open%20Source%20Serial%20Wireless%20Module%20Works%20Great%20with%20Arduino%20IDE%2FMicropython%20(Pack%20of%202PCS)%3A%20Gateway&pos=0&uri=https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Internet-Development-Wireless-Micropython/dp/B010N1SPRK/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=esp8266&qid=1554693478&s=gateway&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1) and I had it plugged in to my computer via usb. I reached accross the board to press the reset button, and it felt like my finger got stung. The best I can figure, I touched the VIN and Gnd pins with my finger, and, I didn't think this at first, the reset pin. Whenever I try to open a serial port all that shows, and at a different baud rate then I specified, is this error message

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

 load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
 tail 8
 chksum 0x2d
 csum 0x2d
 v951aeffa
 ~ld
```

Everything I find online says that this means that the reset pin is causing problems. Although this is the first time a 7 showed up, it used to be a 6. Also, the computer doesn't seem to have a problem uploading the sketches, but they don't seem to run.

I have tried re-flashing the firmware, but just now when I was typing this out, I thought to upload Blink, just to say I could, and it worked, but it isn't sending anything to the computer of serial, at all. I own two of these boards, but the problem happened across both making me think that something happened to my computer.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am running Win 10, using Vscode to upload sketches, and arudino IDE v1.8.7 to monitor serial. I have many Serial.print() lines, and Serial.begin(115200)

Comment: `is this error message` that's not an error message, that's the ESP boot message

Comment: you would not feel the voltages on the ESP8266 pins ..... you would however feel a static electricity discharge from your finger into the board ..... did you walk across a carpet before you touched the board? ..... if it was a static electricity discharge, then there is a good reason to believe that the board has been destroyed

Comment: `rst cause:2` means the boot was due to a reset (perfectly OK) and `boot mode(3,x)` means GPIO15 was LOW, and GPIO0 and GPIO2 were HIGH ... which is what you want when you boot into your sketch ... what's the issue again?

Comment: do you have any `Serial.print()` commands in your sketch? if not, then there wont be any output

Comment: Do you set Generic ESP8266 settings? Try to set DIO

Comment: @JaromandaX forgetting `Serial.begin()` is also classic

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, that makes me feel a lot better, but why would it send this at a different baud rate?

Comment: @jsotola I was sitting in my chair for the last thirty mins reading up on MDNS and the such, and, as I said above, the only clue I got was that my finger felt like it was stung

Comment: @Juraj I am using the NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E) board setting following the instructions on the amazon page. A DIO? (is that a digital I/O pin?

Comment: "Flash mode" in Tools menu. it is not available to set for NodeMcu